# Dissolve only the smaller features among the larger ones

Tags: qgis, dissolve

I want to dissolve features smaller than 1 ha among those larger than 1 ha. For example, if I have 2 features > 1ha and 1 feature < 1 ha, at the end of this process I would like to have 1 original feature and a new one that was the smaller one dissolved into the larger one (it could be dissolved due to proximity). I couldn't find a way to just use QGIS's native dissolve.

Below is a small example. It's not possible to do it manually because I have thousands of features.[image]

Comment: You mention QGIS but don't have a QGIS tag on your question, please edit your tags to show any software/API that you have available. Many would-be helpers filter by tag, leaving the tag off means that they will not see your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can Select the polygons with: `$area<10000` and [Eliminate selected polygons](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgiseliminateselectedpolygons):

> Combines selected polygons of the input layer with certain adjacent
> polygons by erasing their common boundary. The adjacent polygon can be
> either the one with the largest or smallest area or the one sharing
> the largest common boundary with the polygon to be eliminated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select only the features with area > 1ha first and then run the dissolve command on only the selected features.

Comment: Yep then merge, I'd try it on a small dataset first rather than the big one Syner mentions